# How can I perform a git merge while ignoring changed files?

Tags: git, merge, release

I am trying to merge changes from my development branch up into my release branch. However, there have been strange issues where jar files are showing as modified using git status when I have never touched them.

Performing git stash does not undo these changes, and git merge keeps complaining that it cannot merge with these jar file 'changes'. Is there a way to merge branches while ignoring these files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should go back and `*.jar` files to your .gitignore in an early commit (before you first jar file appears in your git history of your development branch).

If you are lucky, rebasing over that will remove the files, more likely, you will have to do an interactive rebase an reset the jar file changes manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the *.jar files as those need not be there in repo by putting that in .gitignore file.

But if you had already committed this file then you will need to do a

```
git rm --cached /\*.jar
```

( --cached since you probably want to keep the local copy but remove from the repo. )